# golang gorilla/mux and rest GET Problems

Tags: rest, go

My Delete Handler:  (I am using "github.com/gorilla/mux")

```
func DeletePerson(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
params := mux.Vars(r)
item := params["id"]
fmt.Println("Item = ", item)
...
```

returns Item = "2"  when called by the following curl command:

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8000/address/2
```

However, my TEST Code:

```
func TestDeletePerson(t *testing.T) {
person := &Person{
    UniqID:    "2",
    FirstName: "",
    LastName:  "",
    EmailAddr: "",
    PhoneNumb: "",
}

jsonPerson, _ := json.Marshal(person)
request, _ := http.NewRequest("DELETE", "/address/2", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonPerson))

response := httptest.NewRecorder()
DeletePerson(response, request)
```

Results in DeletePerson returning ""  and
printing "params" directly returns

```
map[]
```

Big Question - WHAT IN HELL AM I MISSING???

Is there another header parameter I have set?

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't initalize router. Try this

```
func TestDeletePerson(t *testing.T) {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/adress/{id}", DeletePerson).Methods("DELETE")
    request, _ := http.NewRequest("DELETE", "/adress/2", nil)

    response := httptest.NewRecorder()
    r.ServeHTTP(response, request)
}
```

Also I think you dont need to send Person object for deletion

Comment: The router is initialized in tested program.  I went ahead and added

Comment: the router initialization into the golang test function - it didnot fix the problem. I tried to look a gorrilla mux code - but it is not a language I understand, so no help there. I seems like there is something missing that is not obvious that I must add to the request that I do not knnow about.  If Cul can do it, golang sould be able to do it!!!!

Comment: at your example below you forgot to use r.ServeHTTP(response, request), because handler doesn't know anything about your outside routes

Comment: The problem is that your solution does not test my delete handler, "DeletePerson".  Curl calls "DeletePerson" with the line  "curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8000/address/2" and it somehow allows the mux.Vars to find  apparently map["id":"2'"] where the "2" is the record id to delete.  What I can not seem to do is call "DeletePerson:" in such a way the it produces the desired map parameter!!  What is gorillia mux.Vars reading, some intermal header??

Comment: mux.Vars read r.URL and than try to find rule of route with it. My code was not working because I was mistaken with url, now it's work fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your solution does not test my delete handler, "DeletePerson". Curl calls "DeletePerson" with the line "curl -X DELETE localhost:8000/address/2"; and it somehow allows the mux.Vars to find apparently map["id":"2'"] where the "2" is the record id to delete. What I can not seem to do is call "DeletePerson:" in such a way it produces the desired map parameter!! What is gorillia mux.Vars reading, some internal header?? – Godfather 3 hours ago